# Is it possible to output to animated png (.apng) in after effects?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm working on an animation that is going on an iOS app. The animation itself is currently 10x the size of the entire mobile app, so we're looking for alternate ways to compress the filesize. Apparently one of the ways of doing so is to use an animated png rather than a png sequence or a video.

Does anyone have any experience creating apng's?

Comment: Do you want to create the apng inside After Effects?

Answer (score 5):

The Animated Portable Network Graphics (APNG) file format is a non-standard extension to the Portable Network Graphics (PNG) specification. It allows for animated PNG files that work similarly to animated GIF files, while supporting 24-bit images and 8-bit transparency not available for GIFs. It also retains backward compatibility with non-animated PNG files. ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG#Support))

Now what you have to do is export a png sequence from After effects and then upload it to any APNG software:

- [APNG Edit](http://%20APNG%20Editor)
- [Apng anime maker](https://sites.google.com/site/cphktool/apng-anime-maker)
- [APNG Software](http://littlesvr.ca/apng/)
- [Online APNG Assembler](http://littlesvr.ca/apng/assembler/assembler.php)
- [Animizer](http://animizer.net/)
- [Japng Editor](https://www.reto-hoehener.ch/japng/apng_editor.html)

Comment: APNG support in Chrome is here in April 2017

Comment: It now works everywhere except Ms Edge

Comment: @user118753 - doesn't work in Microsoft Explorer either.

Comment: *Now* it does work on MS Edge: https://caniuse.com/?search=apng

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem looking for any adobe products or solution creating apng for snapchat. It's very rare in use because of its compatibility for web browsers.

But if its for an app the go ahead and it will certainly work perfectly with less file size weight.

Us this app, its great.  [PNG Animator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/png-animator/id899480442?mt=12)